# Pharo Smalltalk Method Execution

Tags: methods, arguments, smalltalk, pharo

I have a few test cases that I need to write a method for, and how they execute the method is like this:

```
Planets with: aString , anotherString
```

Where "Planets" is a class and "with:" is a class method. But my confusion is in the way that arguments are given, because I was under the impression that methods with multiple arguments get executed like "methodName: arg1 Arg2: arg2", but in here the two arguments are separated by comma. Can somebody explain this to me please?

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the order of precedence for messages.  Unary messages get handled first, then binary messages, and finally keyword messages.

**Unary** messages have no arguments (*new*, *sqrt*, *isPrime*)

**Binary** messages go between two objects (like a + or in your case the ,).

**Keyword** messages end in a colon (like *with:*) and sometimes there is more than one (like *to:* *do:*)

The binary message , (concatenate two strings) is processed first because it has a higher precedence.  Then the keyword message with: is processed after because it has a lower precedence.  Messages inside of parentheses automatically get the highest precedence and are evaluated first.  When there is a "tie" (multiple messages have the same precedence), they are evaluated left to right.

One weird thing about Smalltalk is that + - * / all have the same binary message precedence.  So 8 + 2 * 4 evaluates to 40 not 16 like you might expect.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the class method `#with:` receives a `String` as its only argument. This means that `#with:` is a *keyword* message with *arity* 1. In the expression

```
Planets with: aString , anotherString
```

there are two messages: (1) the message with selector `#with:` and (2) the message with selector `#,`. The latter has a receiver `aString` and an argument `anotherString`. This is a *binary* message with arity 1 too.

In fact, one could equally write

```
Planets with: (aString , anotherString)
```

to emphasize the role of argument played by the parenthesized expression. We usually don't do that because precedence rules make it unnecessary.

Now note that in the *declaration* of the method with selector`#with:` you would have

```
Planets class >> #with: aString
  "some code here"
```

But one thing is the declaration of a method and another its invocation, in your case

```
Plantes with: aString , anotherString
```

is an expression aimed at sending the message `#with:` to `Planets` with an argument that happens to be the concatenation of two strings.

In sum, when you declare/define the method the argument is `aString`, but when you invoke it (i.e., when you send the message) the argument is *anything* that evaluates to a `String`.

---

As a side note I would indicate that `Planets` isn't a good name for a class. In fact, class names are usually in singular, as they represent a concept, not a collection of instances of said concept.